# rendering a partial in a flash message in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

So I'm just trying to add some social networking share links (facebook, g+, addthis ect) to one of my flash messages when a user successfully uploads a file. I have all the code in a partial so I thought I could just render that but I just get a bunch of "/n"'s and html_safe doesnt work.

here is my partial:

```
 <div class="share_buttons">
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
      <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_stumbleupon"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4e8b938653ac0cd3"></script>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
reddit_target='tattoos'
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.reddit.com/static/button/button1.js"></script>

<% content_for :jquery do %>
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".share_buttons a").live("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/index/share?id=<%= @tattoo.id%>',
          type: 'post'
        });
          return false;
      });
    });
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And in my controller I tried this:

`flash[:success] = "Thanks, feel free to share that out! #{render :partial=> /shared/social_buttons`}"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Need to render it to a string instead

```
flash[:success] = "Thanks, feel free to share that out! #{render_to_string :partial => '/shared/social_buttons'}"
```

Comment: Programmers are very special people! The flash is for rendering little notes and warnings, but naturally at some point I started asking myself, "My flash code is getting kind of ugly... I wonder if I could pull it into a partial?" #nottobeusedfortheotheruse

Comment: you are the life saver. thanx

Comment: To pass variables with the partial render, simply include `locals`. For example: `render_to_string partial: 'path/to/partial', locals: {some_local_var: some_value}` (works in Rails 5)